# Strong Loopback group_by aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, loopback

I have searched a lot to find a way for aggregation using loopback mongodb, unfortunately no perfect solution found. One of them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673606/mongodb-aggregation-on-loopback)
But can't implement this, any one to help me solve this problem, with any new solution, or describing above link.

Answer (score 0):

Loopback doesn't provide a way to do an aggregation query, but you can find another solution in: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/890

```
//Using the datasource we are making a direct request to MongoDB instead of use the PersistedModel of Loopback
var bookCollection = Book.getDataSource().connector.collection(Book.modelName);

bookCollection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: { category: "$category", author: "$author" },
        total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, function(err, groupByRecords) {
    if(err) {
        next(err);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```