# Checking if a field contains a string, works with string type field but not with number

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Loopback node js framework with MongoDB.
Here I am checking if a field contains a given string or not

```
    user.find({
       where: {
        or: [{
         mobile: {
           "regexp": '/' + data.search + '/i'
         },
         contacts:{
           "regexp": '/' + data.search + '/i'
         }}]

      }
   }, function(err, mobileResult) {
    if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
    } else {
    .......
    .......
    }
  });
```

this one works with string type field `contacts` but not with number field `mobile`.

I tried answers from these [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string#10616781) but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Do not use `'/'` and `'/i'`, pass the case insensitive modifier via `$options`.

Comment: I tried but I think, It differs with loopback, It's showing `MongoError: unknown operator: $$regex`.@WiktorStribiżew please read post once again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, In post I have already given the link of same answer, but It didn't worked, please remove tag duplicate.

Comment: I am checking... Did you use `$regex : new RegExp(data.search, "i")`? BTW, you provided a different link in your answer.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, that link is having more answers

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) match patterns in strings. If you need to do pattern matching I'd suggest storing your `mobile` values as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this solution:

1. Using aggregate for querying your data:

> [MongoDB aggregation on Loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673606/mongodb-aggregation-on-loopback)

2. Using this awesome way to search on a number in MongoDB: (Second Answer)

> [MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value)

I also agree with [@Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388319/stennie) which commented:

> Regular expressions match patterns in strings. If you need to do
>   pattern matching I'd suggest storing your mobile values as strings
>   instead of numbers.